# How can I remove the last part of a string?

Tags: php, string

This is my string:

```
monkey/rabbit/cat/donkey/duck
```

If my variable is `cat`...

```
$animal = cat
```

... I want to remove everything coming after `cat`.

My desired result is:

```
monkey/rabbit/cat
```

I tried to use `str_replace`:

```
$subject = 'monkey/rabbit/cat/donkey/duck';
$trimmed = str_replace($animal, '', $subject);
echo $trimmed;
```

But here I get the result:

```
monkey/rabbit//donkey/duck
```

So it is just cutting out `cat`.

Comment: str_replaces *replaces* a piece of string. Try using strpos to get the location of the string(i.e. cat) and then substr to get part of a string

Comment: @JustinJeong Thank you, I will test it!

Comment: You can use explode and echo new variable via array. i.e. $demosubj = exlpode($animal, $subject); echo $demosubj[0].$animal; will get u there

Comment: What happens if the string is `monkey/rabbit/polecat/cat/duck` and you're looking for **cat** ?

Comment: @CD001 Cut after the last `cat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [strpos](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.strpos.php) with [substr](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.substr.php):

```
$pos = strpos($subject, $animal);

if ($pos !== false) {
    $result = substr($subject, 0, $pos + strlen($animal));
}
```

If you wold like to make sure it only the full segments are erased, in case of a partial match, you could use the offset argument of `strpos`:

```
$pos = strpos($subject, $animal);

if ($pos !== false) {
    $result = substr($subject, 0, strpos($subject, '/', $pos));
}
```

Comment: Working very well!

Comment: This could actually fail if you've got both *cat* and *polecat* in the string, or *dog* and *dogfish*.

Comment: @CD001 What do you suggest?

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to make sure only full segments are removed in case of a partial match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` in your case:

```
$string = "monkey/rabbit/cat/donkey/duck";
$val = explode("donkey", $string );

echo $val[0];  

Result: monkey/rabbit/cat
```

PS* Ofcourse there are better ways to do this

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of explanation for what each step does:

```
$subject = 'monkey/rabbit/cat/donkey/duck';

$target = 'cat';
$target_length = strlen($target);                 // get the length of your target string
$target_index = strpos($subject, $target);        // find the position of your target string
$new_length = $target_index + $target_length;     // find the length of the new string
$new_subject = substr($subject, 0, $new_length);  // trim to the new length using substr

echo $new_subject;
```

This can all be combined into one statement.

```
$new_subject = substr($subject, 0, strpos($subject, $target) + strlen($target));
```

This assumes your target is found. If the target is not found, the subject will be trimmed to the length of the target, which obviously is not what you want. For example, if your target string was `"fish"` the new subject would be `"monk"`. This is why the other answer checks `if ($pos !== false) {`.

One of the comments on your question raises a valid point. If you search for a string that happens to be contained in one of the other strings, you may get unexpected results. There is really not a good way to avoid this problem when using the `substr`/`strpos` method. If you want to be sure to only match a complete word between your separators (`/`), you can explode by `/` and search for your target in the resulting array.

```
$subject = explode('/', $subject);                    // convert to array
$index = array_search($target, $subject);             // find the target
if ($index !== false) {                               // if it is found,
    $subject = array_slice($subject, 0, $index + 1);  // remove the end of the array after it
}
$new_subject = implode('/', $subject);                // convert back to string
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to `explode` by your variable.
Take the first part and append the variable.

```
<?php

$string = 'monkey/rabbit/cat/donkey/duck';

$animal = 'cat';

$temp = explode($animal,$string);

print $temp[0] . $animal;
```

Will output nicely

```
monkey/rabbit/cat
```

There's no need to use any of `strpos`, `strlen`, `substr` or `donkeys`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $animal="cat";
    $string1="monkey/rabbit/cat/donkey/duck";
    $parts = explode($animal, $string1);
    $res = $parts[0];
    print("$res$animal")
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably going to kop some flak for going down the RegExp route but...

```
$subject = 'monkey/rabbit/polecat/cat/catfish/duck';
$animal = "cat";
echo preg_replace('~(.*(?:/|^)' . preg_quote($animal) . ')(?:/|$).*~i', "$1", $subject);
```

This will ensure that your *animal* is wrapped immediately on either side with `/` characters, or that it's at the start or end of the string (i.e. *monkey* or *duck*).

So in this example it'll output:

```
monkey/rabbit/polecat/cat
```

Ending specifically with **cat** rather than stumbling at **polecat** or **catfish**

Comment: I think flak happens when regex is used in situations where it's an overkill. This seems like a totally reasonable application of it to me.